# Django Middleware user is always anonymus (REST, SimpleJWT)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using **Django REST Framework** alongside with rest_framework_simplejwt and trying to write my own middleware, that will update `user.last_request` every time user performs one.

````
from django.utils.timezone import now

class LastRequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            request.user.last_request = now()
            request.user.save()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response```
But every time `user.is_authenticated` returns `False'
````

Comment: There is no such thing as middleware in django rest for authentication and you can use token authentication instead.

Answer (score 1):

they were correct about you need to authenticate the user before calling the view. i switched to the authtoken of rest_framework and here is the solution i got to make it work:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed

class UpdateLastActiveMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if not isinstance(request.user, AnonymousUser):
            # User is already authenticated
            profile = request.user.profile
            profile.last_active = timezone.now()
            profile.save()
        else:
            # Attempt to authenticate user using token
            try:
                auth = request.headers.get('Authorization')
                if auth and auth.startswith('Token '):
                    key = auth.split(' ')[1]
                    user, _ = TokenAuthentication().authenticate_credentials(key)  # Extract user from tuple
                    request.user = user
                    profile = request.user.profile
                    profile.last_active = timezone.now()
                    profile.save()

                else:
                    raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid token')
            except (Token.DoesNotExist, AuthenticationFailed):
                # Token authentication failed, user remains unauthenticated
                pass

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to fix this problem is to authenticate user inside middleware manually. New code looks like this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication


class LastRequestMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        user = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)[0]

        if user:
            user = user[0]
            if user.is_authenticated:
                user.last_request = now()
                user.save(update_fields=['last_request'])
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

This is an easy-fix, so if you need user authentication functionality in many middlewares, consider using separate AuthMiddleware for SimpleJWT authentication.

Comment: Try to get the `request.user` after calling `self.get_response()`. This is because the authentication in case of DRF happens in the view. So after processing the response, `request.user` should have been filled up by the api view

Comment: I thnk that with a middleware you authenticate the user twice, once in the middleware and the other within the drf-simple-jwt view.

Comment: @BrianDestura This method does not work if you want to do something before response

Comment: this answer is for use case when you need authenticated user before calling view